# How can I toggle one switch based on another with CSS?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Here is [what I have been trying](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GL2QT4D0AIFT).

What should go into the javascript function `myFunc()` to get 'Switch-2' to enable [with gray background turning blue] when I click on 'Switch-1' and vice-versa. I'm fairly new to CSS or jQuery. I believe the solution should be using one of these or both. Would be of great help if someone can share the code to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```js
function myFunc() {
  var checkBox1 = document.getElementById("SW1");
  var checkBox2 = document.getElementById("SW2");
  
  if (checkBox1.checked == true){
    alert("SW2:"+checkBox2.checked);
    //How to Enable SW2 with blue background
  } else {
     alert("SW2:"+checkBox2.checked);
     //How to Disable SW2 with gray background
  }
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label>Switch 1: </label>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="SW1" onclick="myFunc()">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br><br>

<label>Switch 2: </label>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="SW2">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/ (or "link")

Comment: You shouldn't have two label elements. That's also an accessibility problem.

Comment: Isn't there some form data or JavaScript functionality to go with this? What's the point of just doing a visual toggle? You'd have to update the checkbox state anyway, right?

Comment: If you're looking for a JavaScript solution, there are [many to be found](https://www.google.com/search?q=toggle+switch+from+another+with+jquery+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&sxsrf=ALeKk03Vh46AyKKzPyGpUoiyHQpktLKoRg:1606312594181&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidy8vc7J3tAhU-STABHTqeAosQrQIoBHoECAcQBQ&biw=1618&bih=947).

Comment: Yes, say i have a button 'Enable' or 'Disable', which would call a JavaScript function, that in turn would toggle 'Switch-1' or 'Switch-2' in my question.

Comment: That code should be in your post, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to do? Try running the snippet.

```js
function switchClicked(currentSwitchState, switchToToggle) {
  var switchElement = document.getElementById(switchToToggle);
  switchElement.checked = currentSwitchState.checked;  
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label>Switch 1: </label>
<label class="switch">
  <input id="s1" type="checkbox" onclick="switchClicked(this, 's2');">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br><br>

<label>Switch 2: </label>
<label class="switch">
  <input id="s2" type="checkbox" onclick="switchClicked(this, 's1');">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```